# Java endorsed and Netbeans

Tags: java, jax-ws, endorsed, netbeans-7.4

I'm using Netbeans as an IDE while programing Java. Recently new version of NetBeans has arrived. So I've installed it and import one of my project group. This group has project with some web clients that use jax-ws.

I know all the troubles with such projects while upgrading Netbeans and I know how to workaround them (delete endorsed library, create new jax-ws project and so on). But this time situation is more complicated. NetBeans 7.4 uses JDK 7 and I have to deploy my projects under Java 6. When I "clean and build" my projects for Netbeans' default Java platform (Java 7) everything is ok and there is no usage of JAX-WS-ENDORSED lib.

When I changed NetBeans'platform to Java 6 (previously created in IDE) I recieved error messages (no such method... etc) which I familiar with - they arise because of version of Jax-ws in JDK 6. I've created endorsed lib (using the trick with dummy project) but there was no effect.

Then I added endorsed.classpath=${libs.JAX-WS-ENDORSED.classpath} line to project.properties (in nbproject directory) and errors were disappeared. But after restarting IDE this line disappeared from project.properties file and errors came back. I tried to add such a line to private.properties file but after that I got error "No such library" during "clean and build" process. So now each time I restart Netbeans I open project.properties and manually add endorsed.classpath line to it.

*Here is a question:*

How can I make this line: `endorsed.classpath=${libs.JAX-WS-ENDORSED.classpath}` to stay in `project.properties` file permanently?